# append int values in an emty array java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I wrote a programm to print out all the prime number up to a limit. Then put those prime numbers into an ArrayList, convert this ArrayList into an array, finally print the numbers out with their index.

Note: I couldnt print out an ArrayList with a for loop, it's possible with an array only, hence the conversion.

My question is:

Is there anyway to do it without pushing the numbers into an ArrayList first, instead put them right away into an emty array of a length < given limit.

Thanks for you help!
was browsing SO in the last 2 days and couldnt find anything

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args){

    //get input till which prime number to be printed
    System.out.print("Enter the number till which prime number to be printed: ");

    int limit = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    System.out.print("\n");

    ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();



    //printing primer numbers till the limit ( 1 to 10)
    System.out.println("Printing prime number from 1 to " + limit + "\n");

    for(int number=2; number <= limit; number++){
        if(isPrime.numberPrime(number)){
            myArray.add(number);    
        }   
    }

    System.out.println(myArray + "\n");


    //Convert ArrayList into an Array
    int[] newArray = new int[myArray.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {

            newArray[i] = myArray.get(i);

    }
    System.out.println("There were " + myArray.size() + " prime numbers");
    System.out.println("Index\tValue");

    for(int counter = 0; counter<newArray.length; counter++){
        System.out.println(counter+1 + "\t" + newArray[counter]);
    }

}
```

here is the result:
    Enter the number till which prime number to be printed: 10

```
Printing prime number from 1 to 10

[2, 3, 5, 7]

There were 4 prime numbers
Index   Value
1   2
2   3
3   5
4   7
```

Comment: may i ask why you couldn´t print the `ArrayList` within an loop?

Comment: You don't need to move the numbers in the ArrayList to a normal array, you could just loop with and print arraylist.get(i). Alternatively, you could just use System.out.println(arraylist.toString());

Comment: OK, i was too tired and overcomplicated it :D. What I forgot when printing the ArrayList is to use the get() method, thats why it didnt work (sight). Thanks Swailem95

Comment: BTW, is it possible to put int values into an emty array, given that its size is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do this

```
//Convert ArrayList into an Array
int[] newArray = new int[myArray.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {

        newArray[i] = myArray.get(i);

}
System.out.println("There were " + myArray.size() + " prime numbers");
System.out.println("Index\tValue");

for(int counter = 0; counter<newArray.length; counter++){
    System.out.println(counter+1 + "\t" + newArray[counter]);
}
```

In place of this, simply write

```
System.out.println("There were " + myArray.size() + " prime numbers");
System.out.println("Index\tValue");
for(int i=0;i<myArray.size();i++)
System.out.println(i+1 + "\t" + myArray.get(i));
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to use the get() method. But is there a way to do this with an array, without using ArrayList ?